# Executed Query Performs Differently to Query (identity insert on is used)

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to loop through tables and insert the records from one db to another so I want to keep things dynamic. If I run the following I get an error

```
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(max) = 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT [NEW].[dbo].[TABLE] ON'

EXEC    (@command)

DECLARE @command2 NVARCHAR(max) = 'Insert Into [NEW].[dbo].[TABLE] ([ID], [Description], [SiteID], [Active]) Select [ID], [Description], [SiteID], [Active] from [OLD].[dbo].[TABLE]'

EXEC    (@command2)
```

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TABLE' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

If I run the commands on their own (not as executable strings) everything works fine. My guess is that it builds @command and @command2 before execution and when it finds the problem it throws an error before trying to execute.

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Why are you running them in string at all? There's no need.

Answer (score 1):

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT` options set inside dynamic SQL will be reset when that scope exits.

You would need to set the option inside the same dynamic SQL string that is depending on it being on. This can contain multiple statements (ideally semi colon terminated)